# Dart double toStringAsFixed rounds the number, but it shouldn't

Tags: string, flutter, dart, parsing, double

I have a Flutter project, in SharedPrefs, I'm storing a double id, from a Third-part API. (so I can only get it as a double)

The id from prefs is `43449716574226770.0`

I have to parse this double to a String, I'm doing it like this:

```
String idString = id.toStringAsFixed(0)
```

What I'm getting is somehow: `43449716574226768`  but I'd like it to be just  `43449716574226770`

I have tried `.toInt().toString()`  too, with the same results.

The weirdest part is that it sometimes works, with other ids.

Comment: an id stored as a double?? why? if it is used as a string then store it as a string, not double

Comment: @pskink If I convert it to string there, the same error applies..

Comment: you dont need to convert string to string - keep it in `SharedPrefs` as a string and you will not need to convert anything

Comment: Its not a string, it's a double from the API, sadly I can't change how the API gives it to me

Comment: Your number is too large to be exactly representable by the 53 bits of precision for a `double`'s significand.  Low bits therefore will get discarded.  Use an `int` for more precision (on non-web platforms) or use `BigInt` or `String` for an arbitrary amount of precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number as long would be in a 6-byte range?
As double this with an exponent part, this might mean that the previous double (bit wise) would have a difference more than 1. Also see [java Math.ulp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ulp(double)).

This implies that using a `double` instead of a `long` maps some double IDs to the same "long" ID.

*I am not sure this is the problem here, but it would explain a deviation of 2.*

Answer (score 1):

[image]Can you please try this

```
double x=43449716574226770.0;
print(x.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it `id.round().toString()`, it will work.

Comment: .round() would not work for us, if the end of the number is 771.0 it rounds it to 770

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it here and it didn't round 771.0 to 770